# Apt upgrade fail because of phpmyadmin (Updating debian 10 to 11)

Tags: php, shell, phpmyadmin, apt, debian-buster

I'm trying to update a debian 10 server to 11. It runs an apache2 server with some php7.3, and uses a mariadb with phpmyadmin.

I followed a few tutorials in vain ([last one I used](https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-debian-10-to-debian-11/)). Everything works pretty well until I use `sudo apt full-upgrade` It manages to download the packages, but when it gets to phpmyadmin it crashes.

```
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../30-phpmyadmin_4%3a5.0.4+dfsg2-2+deb11u1_all.deb ...
Determining localhost credentials from /etc/mysql/debian.cnf: succeeded.
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/hint' not owned by package 'phpmyadmin:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/hint/sql-hint.js' not owned by package 'phpmyadmin:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.js' not owned by package 'phpmyadmin:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css' not owned by package 'phpmyadmin:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: directory '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/codemirror/addon/hint' contains files not owned by package phpmyadmin:all, cannot switch to symlink
dpkg: erreur de traitement de l'archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-7oxSMZ/30-phpmyadmin_4%3a5.0.4+dfsg2-2+deb11u1_all.deb (--unpack) :
 new phpmyadmin package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

However it still manages to install debian 11 (I checked with `lsb_release -a`), but makes apt behave oddly, as I don't seem to have mysql anymore and the website can't connect to it.

```bash
root@SERV-TEST-UPDATE-v2:/home/informatique# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

Also doing an `apt update` after the error tells me that my 300+ packages can be updated. And an `apt fix-broken install` don't help.

Does anyone know where is the problem ?

Comment: Is there a chance you manually installed phpMyAdmin over top of the package at some point? I think my suggestion would be to remove the old package (save your configuration or "remove" instead of "purge"), let Apt fix everything else, then install phpMyAdmin again. Are you using the phpMyAdmin suggested package sources or the package included from Debian?

Comment: I was not the one to create this server, it's at least 8 years old. I'll try to reinstall it manually as per your last comment.